# Computing $A(x) = \underbrace{x * x * \cdots * x}_{n\ times}$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Let $*$ be an internal binary operation such that:

$$(\forall(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2)\ x*y = x \cdot \sqrt{1+y^2} + y \cdot \sqrt{1+x^2}$$

and let $ (\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R})\ f(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} $ be a bijective homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R},*)$ such that $f^{-1}(x) = \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})$

I want to compute $A(x) = \underbrace{x * x * \cdots * x}_{n\ times}$

I solved it as follows:

Since $f$ is a bijective homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R},*)$, then $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},*)$ to $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Using that gives $$f^{-1}(x * x * \cdots * x) = f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(x) + \cdots f^{-1}(x)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x * x * \cdots * x) = n \cdot f^{-1}(x)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow f(f^{-1}(x * x * \cdots * x)) = f(n \cdot f^{-1}(x))$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x * x * \cdots * x = f(n \cdot \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1}))$$

$$\Leftrightarrow A(x) = f(\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})^n)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow A(x) = \frac{(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})^n - (x + \sqrt{x^2+1})^{-n}}{2}$$

Is it possible to further simplify $A(x)$?

Answer (score 6):

The hyperbolic trigonometric identities $\;\sinh(x+y) = \sinh(x)\cosh(y)+\sinh(y)\cosh(x),\;$ and $\cosh(x)=\sqrt{1+\sinh(x)^2}\;$ together imply that $\;\sinh(x)*\sinh(y)=\sinh(x+y),\;$ and therefore $\;A(\sinh(x))=\sinh(nx)\;$ which can also be written as $\;A(x)=\sinh(n\sinh^{-1}(x)).\;$ Because $f(x)=\sinh(x),\;$ this answer is equivalent to what is in the question but I think it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! $A(x)=\sinh(n\sinh^{-1}(x))$ is exactly $A(x) = f(\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})^n)$ I don´t know how does your reply contribute to answer the question.

Comment: @AyoubFalah. Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Ayoub Falah I am sorry but the "added value" of Somos is that he has given a simpler expression than yours using "sinh" that wasn't present in your text !

Comment: @Somos Nice and nonrude answer.